# ¿Cómo puedo pasar imagenes a cloud firestore en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una BD en Cloud Firestore, en donde listo caracteristicas de articulos y una de ellas es la foto que logro conseguirla con un uri si es de la galeria y la ruta en string si es una foto (la foto se guarda en los archivos de la app en el dispositivo). La cuestion es como puedo pasarlo para luego mostrarlo en un recyclerview que ya tengo creado y funciona pero no muestra la foto.
He visto varios metodos que lo hacen con el Storage, pero quiero saber si es mas comodo usarlo dentro de la bd con el atributo de tipo referencia

Comment: Hola , recuerda agregar lo que trataste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías de comprobar en tu gradle haber si has metido la librería del storage de firebase.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
```

Luego te dejo aquí el ejemplo de una app que hice yo en la cual subía imagenes a firestore.

```
   private StorageReference mStorage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Aquí creas el metodo de obtención de la imagen ya sea por galeria o camara
        //Luego del metodo de obtención llamas al metodo y te lo subiría directamente
        //creando una carpeta "Fotos" en caso de que no exista

}
private void SubirProducto() {
        final StorageReference FilePath = mStorage.child("Fotos").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());


        FilePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

              //Esto seria para descargar su token de enlace y poder acceder a ella
              //Si no lo quieres poner no hace falta
              FilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       
                    }
                });

            }
        });


    }
```